SMS receiving and autofill in html input text by WebView
I want receive sms activation code and only code(no text) autofill in the specified input after receiving the SMS, I receiving SMS, but I don't know the rest.
How do i do?
html:
<form action="/auth/login" id="getactivcode" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="code" class="numeren" autocomplete="off" id="libino" maxlength="4">
</form>

AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.site.gilali">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.gilali">

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.site.gilali.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".ReceiveSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>

MainActivity.java:
package com.site.gilali;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mWebView;
//    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
//        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        String siteUrl = "https://gilali.com/";
        mWebView.loadUrl(siteUrl);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == 1000){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private class mWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
//            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading page...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
//            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}

ReceiveSms.java:
package com.site.gilali;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReceiveSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] msgs;
            String msg_from;
            if(bundle != null){
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                        Toast.makeText(context, "From: "+msg_from+", Body: "+msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//msgBody -> active code:5241
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

i want just separate the code from the text of the message and place it in the field after receiving the sms?
